# Typescript: How to convert string date to date

Tags: typescript

How to convert string date to date? For example

```
let oldDate = "24.01.2017";
let newDate = new Date(oldDate);
```

I did a console log and I see that typeof newDate is object and if I do console log of newDate, it's displaying as invalid Date.
I don't want to use any other third party js like moment JS.
How to resolve this?

Comment: `let newDate = new Date(...oldDate.split(".").reverse().map(Number));`

Comment: @dandavis No luck